# How to use DigiCert Signing Manager Controller (smctl) in Azure DevOps classic pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, code-signing, digicert, smctl

This following task, which signs a setup program using DigiCert Signing Manager Controller (smctl), works without any problem, if I use it in a Azure YAML pipeline.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Sign setup file'
  inputs:
    script: 
      smctl sign --verbose --keypair-alias=$(digicert-key-pair-alias) --certificate=$(Agent.TempDirectory)\KeyCert.pem  --config-file $(SSMClientToolsSetup.PKCS11_CONFIG) --input $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
  env:
    SM_HOST: $(CodeSigningHost)
    SM_API_KEY: $(digicert-api-key)
    SM_CLIENT_CERT_PASSWORD: $(digicert-cert-pw)
    SM_CLIENT_CERT_FILE: $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
```

Using the exact same task in an Azure DevOps release pipeline doesn't work: See this screenshot:

[image: Signing task]

I'm getting this error:

```
Command : 
 signtool sign  /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td SHA256  /fd  SHA256   /csp "DigiCert Signing Manager KSP" /kc "***" /f "D:\a\_temp\KeyCert.pem"  "D:\a\1\a\setup\ApplicationService_Setup_4.2.0.57.exe" 
Error : 
Done Adding Additional Store
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146893779/0x8009002d)
 
 exit status 1: SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

I'm calling in both pipelines the same necessary tasks as described in DigiCert [instructions](https://docs.digicert.com/ko/software-trust-manager/ci-cd-integrations/plugins/azure-devops-client-tools-extension.html#-en--create-an-authentication-certificate-436085). The DigiCert tools are downloaded and installed correctly in both pipelines. The necessary certificate and all environment variables are also there.

For my understanding the signing process should work in both types of pipelines. I'm calling the same tasks in both pipelines. Both pipelines have access to the secure file containing the certificate to sign and to the variable group, that contains the secret parameters used by the DigiCert tools.

Comment: 1. Have you set the `Reference name` of your Download secure file task to "caCertificate"? 2. The difference I can see is that you are using `smctl sign` in the yaml but `smctl signature` in the classic release. Not sure if it has any impact.  3. Add a variable named `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in both yaml and release pipelines. Compare the debug logs of the two builds and check what's the differences.

Comment: 4. You can also set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run the release pipeline on it. Then check the local Event Viewer for more info. See [SignTool errors and solutions](https://docs.digicert.com/en/software-trust-manager/troubleshoot/signtool-errors-and-solutions.html) for the detailed steps.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT
1. "Reference name" is set 2. I tried both sign and signature. Both doesn't work 3. I set system.debug to true, but couldn't find any differences beside the output of smctl error msg from classic pipeline. 4. I can't find the error msg -2146893779 in your "SignTool errors" link